# Does Google Cloud CDN support to cache webpages?

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, cloud, cdn

I read an article about Google Cloud CDN, and it said Google CDN only supports to cache static contents, such as images, css files, but not web pages.

So I wonder whether that is case? And whether I can define custom rules that support to cache web pages.

In a word, my purchase is to cache the whole sites, including both the pages and the static resources.

**Note:
My site is built with WordPress. So what I mean is whether Google CDN can cache dynamic pages.**

Comment: the pages are HTML pages or dynamic pages? (like php, node, python and so on)

Comment: The Google Cloud CDN supports caching web pages. Which document are you referring to? **Cache Mode: FORCE_CACHE_ALL** - *Unconditionally caches responses, overring any cache directives set by the origin. This mode is not appropriate if the backend serves private, per-user content, such as dynamic HTML or API responses.* You can also select what is cached and for how long with cache headers.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia, dynamic pages, My site is built with WordPress.

Comment: @JohnHanley, How about WordPress sites? The WordPress site pages are dynamic PHP pages.

Comment: That depends. A lot of WordPress sites use caching. Depends on your definition of dynamic pages. Typically a blog page does not change often. An index page of blog posts would change whenever a post is added/deleted/updated. Caching is controlled by cache headers. For example, my WordPress site is set to cache everything for 24 hours. If I need to update the cache, I manually flush the cache. The topic of caching can be complex depending on what is being cached, the cache servers, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley, seems rather complex. I use WP Rocket as the cache plugin.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a software development and programming site. Create a question that is on-topic. At this point, you are asking for recommendations and opinions which is off-topic. Try using Quora and Reddit after hitting the books on caching and CDNs.

Comment: @JohnHanley, Thank you for your advice. I post the question here because in Google Cloud Platform, they said to seek supports one can ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, this is a good site for Google Cloud Platform (and Azure, AWS, PHP, C#, etc.). The goal for Stack Overflow is questions that can be answered with facts or citations or code and not with chatter about technology. Think of it this way. Ask to-the-point questions and get to-the-point answers. In some cases from subject matter experts.

Comment: @JohnHanley, with Cache Mode: FORCE_CACHE_ALL, my contents are still not cached due to Vary Header containing "User Agent". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447859/google-cloud-cdn-force-cache-all-content-not-cache-all-content