# Google Cloud CDN "Force Cache All Content" NOT Cache All Content

Tags: caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cdn

I am using Google Cloud CDN for my WordPress website https://cdn.datanumen.com. I have enabled "Force Cache All Content" option. However, the web pages, css files, javascript files are still not cached. Only the images are cached.

For example, I test the page at https://cdn.datanumen.com/, I have used Ctrl + F5 to refresh the webpage for many times, but always get the same results.

Below is the web page I try to load:

[image]

There are "Cache-Control" field in the response header, but no "Age" field. Based on Google document, if a cache hits and cached content is served, there will be a "Age" field. So without "Age" means the file is not cached.

I also check the log:

[image]

In the log, cacheFillBytes is 26776 and cacheLookup is true. It seems that Google CDN is trying to lookup cache and fill cache with the contents. But the statusDetails shows "response_sent_by_backend", so the contents are still served from the backend. Normally this should only occur for the first time when I visit the website. But for my case, even if I press Ctrl + F5 to refresh my website for many times, I will always get the same result, the statusDetails never shows "response_sent_by_cache" for page such as https://cdn.datanumen.com/

Why?

**Update:**

I notice there is a "Vary" field in the response header:

[image]

Based on https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#non-cacheable_content, if Vary header    Has a value other than Accept, Accept-Encoding, or Origin, then the content will not be cached, since for my case "Vary" header is "Accept-Encoding,Cookie,User-Agent", it is not cached. But my question is how to deal with issue and let the content be cached forcely?

**Update 2**

I have changed the site to a real WordPress site, since that is what I need finally. I plan to use Google Cloud CDN purchased support to see if they can help on this case.

Comment: Have you tried removing the value of `User-Agent` in the HTTP header of your back-end?

Comment: @AlexG, How to remove the User-Agent tag?

Comment: Hi OP, I tried accessing your website, ran the dev tool (Chrome, Safari) and it appears that files are properly cached after a refresh from the browsers. Still I'm not sure if things are working as expected on your end now.

Comment: @Dondi, Sorry for the confusion. To make the thing more clear, I stop the Cloud CDN on www.datanumen.org and run it on www.sqlserver-recovery.com instead. As the latter is a WordPress site and what I want is to cache a WordPress site.

Comment: @Dondi, I have updated the article content so that it is more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.siteground.com/blog/vary-http-header/) article. https://www.siteground.com/blog/vary-http-header/

Answer (score 2):

According to the Google Cloud CDN's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cache-modes), the best way to solve your problem is actually using the ***CACHE_ALL_STATIC*** cache mode:

- **CACHE_ALL_STATIC**: Automatically caches static content that doesn't have the no-store or private directive. Origin responses that set valid caching directives are also cached. This is the default behavior for Cloud CDN-enabled backends created by using the gcloud command-line tool or the REST API.
- **USE_ORIGIN_HEADERS**: Requires origin responses to set valid cache directives and valid caching headers. Responses without these directives are forwarded from the origin.
- **FORCE_CACHE_ALL**: Unconditionally caches responses, overring any cache directives set by the origin. This mode is not appropriate if the backend serves private, per-user content, such as dynamic HTML or API responses.

But in the case of the last cache mode, there are **two warnings** about its usage:

1. When you set the cache mode to FORCE_CACHE_ALL, the default time to live (TTL) for content caching is **3600 seconds (1 hour)**, unless you explicitly set a different TTL. Accepting the new default TTL of 1 hour might cause some entries that were previously considered fresh (due to having longer TTLs from origin headers) to now be considered stale.
2. The FORCE_CACHE_ALL mode overrides **cache directives (Cache-Control and Expires)** but **does not override other origin response headers**. In particular, a Vary header is still honored, and may suppress caching even in the presence of FORCE_CACHE_ALL. For more information, see Vary headers.

Comment: Thank you. I notice tha the Vary Header for the not cached items are "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent" so make it uncachable by CDN. My question is how to work around with issue and force the items being cached?

Comment: According to this section, it seems it will be difficult: